# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bundle.js' in '/Users/jonathankuhl/Documents/Programming/node js/sandbox/webpack-app'

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I am trying to go through a very basic tutorial about Webpack.  I cannot get it to compile a very basic single line javascript application.  I have installed and uninstalled it multiple times.

It's just a tutorial to learn how to use Webpack.  I used `npm init` to set up the `package.json` and did nothing else to touch that file.  I have a single index.html file and a single app.js file that is suppose to bundle into a bundle.js file.

I enter: `webpack app.js bundle.js` into the terminal

I keep getting this error:

```
Jonathans-MBP:webpack-app jonathankuhl$ webpack app.js bundle.js
Hash: 8d502a6e1f30f2ad64ab
Version: webpack 4.1.1
Time: 157ms
Built at: 2018-3-20 12:25:32
 1 asset
Entrypoint main = main.js
   [0] ./app.js 18 bytes {0} [built]
   [1] multi ./app.js bundle.js 40 bytes {0} [built]

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for this environment.

ERROR in multi ./app.js bundle.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bundle.js' in '/Users/jonathankuhl/Documents/Programming/node js/sandbox/webpack-app'
 @ multi ./app.js bundle.js
```

Here's the package.json, there's nothing in it that I didn't do outside of `npm init`:

```
{
"name": "webpack-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "testing",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  I'm literally doing exactly what the tutorial is telling me to do, step by step.  I don't know much about webpack, thought I should look into it, since I want a job in web development.  I don't know what it means by "can't resolve 'bundle.js'.  It's as if bundle.js doesn't exist, but it's not supposed to exist, webpack creates it.

I've tried alternatives such as doing `npm run build` after adding `"build":"webpack"` to my package.json under `"scripts"`, and had no luck.  That was before I deleted the entire directory and started over.  I've installed and uninstalled both webpack and webpack-cli a few times as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the tut, if it matters: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lziuNMk_8eQ  It's a little less than a year old, so maybe it's slightly outdated?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

you need `bundle.js` as output so try instead this command

`webpack app.js -o bundle.js`

Comment: That's what I was missing.  Thank you.

Comment: unbelievable, after 2 hours of research the -o was missing puzzle... why they said nothing about it in any documentation

Comment: Webpack documentation is not nice for beginners at all... I had to install webpack globally then installed webpack cli globally then install webpack locally again before it worked

Comment: Has anything changed with newest version of webpack? This command: webpack app.js -o bundle.js opens file app.js in my default application for .js files instead of building the file.

Comment: @FrenkyB it is working as expected, at least for me. Check `webpack.config` maybe smth there.

Answer (score 6):

I also needed to set the mode explicitly

```
webpack --mode=development app.js -o bundle.js
```

to proceed with that tutorial.